# With humans, is being transgender innate, or caused by social factors?

Tags: human-biology, gender

In humans, is being transgender something that is innate, or is it caused (or made more likely) by social factors such as their political beliefs, their religious views or their social environment?

Comment: Something interesting  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/25667367

Comment: Transgender is a collective name for a wide variety of cases, the hormonal changes occurs in embryonic stage result in transgender case at birth time itself, for most other cases it is occurred in the puberty period.